# find $\theta_{MLE}$ for a function

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

For 
$$
f(x;\theta)=(\theta+1)x^{-\theta-2}
$$
find the maxmimum likelihood estimators (MLEs) for $\theta$ based on a random sample of size $n$.
My work so far:
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^n \log(f(x_i;\theta)) &= \sum \log(\theta+1)-\log(x_i)(\theta+2) \\
&=n\log(\theta+1)-(\theta+2)\sum \log(x_i)
\end{align}
$$
Now take the derivative, and set it equal to 0:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \log(f(x;\theta)) &= 0-(\theta+2)\sum \frac{1}{x_i} =0 \\
&=\sum\frac{1}{x_i}=0
\end{align}
$$
I cant make any sense of this. What exactly have I done here? Did something go wrong? Shouldnt I get an equation with $\theta$ in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take the derivative with respect to $\theta$.

Also, $\prod_{i=1}^n \log(f(x_i;\theta))$ should be $\sum_{i=1}^n \log(f(x_i;\theta))$

Comment: ok now im getting
$$
\theta_{MLE} = \frac{n}{\sum log(x_i)} -1
$$

But this seems wrong.

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: Because I dont know whether or not it is right. :(

Comment: Ive checked it, it is right, thank you very much :)